# Difference between Database and Data Source

Tags: database, datasource

What is the difference between Database and Data Source?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A data source is simply something your program relies on to get data. A database is a kind of data source that persists data to some digitized form. Other data sources include files, services, etc — these all provide data to your programs.

Answer (score 14):

Further to BoltClock's answer, here are example of Databases (or Database Servers) vs various Data Sources.

**Databases**

1. SQL
2. Oracle
3. MySQL

**Data Sources**

1. All of the **databases** above
2. XML Files
3. CSV Files
4. Web Services
5. and many many more..

Comment: The list of 'databases' is actually a list of DBMS - Database Management Systems.

Answer (score 2):

Data Source may not be connected to DB, it can be just file system or any source of data.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [description from Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/30323/data-source):

> A data source, in the context of computer science and computer
>   applications, is the location where data that is being used come from.
>   In a database management system, the primary data source is the
>   database, which can be located in a disk or a remote server. The data
>   source for a computer program can be a file, a data sheet, a
>   spreadsheet, an XML file or even hard-coded data within the program.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple word, I will try to answer this question.

First, we need to understand data sources, Data source is something from where we get data to analyze or a place where data is stored. Kinds of different data sources are:

**1. Databases**
**2. Flat files, Excel sheets, Spread Sheets**
**3. Web Services, Etc.**

Now come to the database as in the above examples we can see there is mentioned database, which is one of the kinds of data sources. In databases companies stores their collections of records, responses, survey, etc. In databases there are two types:
**1. DBMS:** Database management system
**2. RDBMS:** Relational Database Management system

Answer (score -1):

Data ---  image, video,  file , pdf,msg, name, age, height, weight, etc

Database is a collection of data (contact number, best friend names, shopping list is a collection of data) stored in a formet Systematically that can be easily accessed.

Example of database: attendance register

1. Attendance register of employees in office
2. Attendance register of students in school

Attandance register is a database

- Database store in computer , mobile , tables, excel, folders etc

Types of database: Network Database, Object-Oriented Database, Relational Database, Hierarchical Database like attendance register, attendance page, attendance darry.

Database Management System (DBMS)------- A database management system (DBMS) is a software package  create, manipulate, retrieve and manage data in a database .A DBMS generally manipulates the data itself, the data format, field names, record structure and file structure. It also defines rules to validate and manipulate this data. example of DBMS---> HR, Teacher.

1. Hr, Teacher maintain register  same as Dbms maintain database ...

   ```
                           ________database create ________
                          |                               |
                    MANUALLY                         Electrically 
                  (Hands)                       ( computer,mobilephones etc)
                   using pen, paper               using  DBMS software, File system etc
   ```

A DATABASE store the data and provide a method to access it, a DBMS actually converts the queries into a meaningful command, to invoke the method used to access the database.

Some other DBMS (teacher, HR) examples include:

- MySQL ( example ->eng teacher)
- SQL Server ( hindi teacher)
- Oracle ( evs teacher)
- dBASE   ( senior teacher)
- FoxPro   ( math teacher)

All teacher maintain attendance register same as all this DBMS maintain database..

Principal or head decide which teacher is create and maintain register  same as developer decide  which DBMS( my sql, oracle) is create and maintain database and which is best.

Find rohan total attendance?

Find rohan total attendance --------> HR/Teacher -----------> Attandance register

Find rohan total attendance------> DBMS(my sql)  --------->database

SQL (Structured query language)

NOSQL

SQL--------- SQL stands for Structured Query Language. SQL is used to communicate with a database
              it is the standard language for relational database management systems. SQL statements are used to perform tasks such as update data on a
              database, or retrieve data from a database. Some common DBMS( Oracle, Sybase, Microsoft SQL Server, Access, Ingres, My sql, Oracle,Sqlite) that use 
              Sql . Sql database is tablebase database like Ms excel, vertically data store, relational database.
              In NOSQL data is store in key value, pair like json...NOSQL used by---Redis , MongoDB.   example ofsql , sql is class monitor or head student of class 
               that is help to the DBMS( Teacher, Hr) to manage Database (Register)...  one  class monitor helps all teacher same as one SQL Used by many dbms
               (My sql , oracle )

```
         Purpose .. To query and operate database system.



                                              SQL use by                     NOSQL  use by
                                        1.My sql                             1.Redis 
                                        2.Ms-sql                             2.MongoDB etc
                                        3. oracle etc
                                             |                                     |                       
                                             |_______________DBMS__________________|
```

Comment: So... "what is the difference between Database and Data Source ?"  I read you answer, but I failed to find a mention of a "Data Source" :-(  (For that matter, what is a "Data Source" ?)  I applaud the desire to answer this question (nearly 10 years after it was asked).  But I confess to being unable to imagine why you would want to :-(